# Erlang - mySQL Запись в базу

Tags: mysql, erlang

Доброго времени суток. Я новый человек в Эрланге по-этому есть некие проблемы при решении определенных задач.

На данный момент необходимо сделать crud api mySQL через Erlang
Коннект и чтение БД проходит нормально, но вот с записью есть проблемы

Использую либу https://github.com/Eonblast/Emysql

Есть таблица с атрибутами (id, time, info, status)
id, time, status - прописываются автоматом в таблицу, а вот info я передаю в функцию.

```
-module(sql_app).
-export([start/0, insert/1, select/0, select/1]).

start() -> 
  application:start(emysql),
  emysql:add_pool(erlang, [{size,1}, {user,"root"}, {password,"root"},
        {host,"localhost"}, {port,3306},{database,"erlang"}, {encoding,utf8}]).
%% Id, Time, Info, Status
insert(Info) -> 
Id = 25,
Status = true,
Time = 89600,
    emysql:prepare(id, <<"INSERT INTO erlang_table SET id = ?">>),
    emysql:execute(erlang, id, [Id]),

    emysql:prepare(status, <<"INSERT INTO erlang_table SET status = ?">>),
    emysql:execute(erlang, status, [Status]),

    emysql:prepare(time, <<"INSERT INTO erlang_table SET time = ?">>),
    emysql:execute(erlang, time, [Time]),

    emysql:prepare(info, <<"INSERT INTO erlang_table SET info = ?">>),
    Result = emysql:execute(erlang, info, [Info]),

        io:format("~n~p~n", [Result]).

select() ->
    Result = emysql:execute(erlang, <<"SELECT * from erlang_table">>),
      io:format("~n~p~n", [Result]).

select(Id) -> 
    emysql:prepare(stmt, <<"SELECT * from erlang_table WHERE id = ?">>),
    Data = emysql:execute(erlang, stmt, [Id]),
      io:format("~n~p~n", [Data]).
```

Подскажите как сделать так, чтоб я сначала был emysql:prepare по всем данным (id, time, status, info), а только потом emysql:execute ???
Потому, что сейчас данные в таблицу записываются в разные строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кроме того, что я новичок в Эранге, я еще и новичок в БД.
Решение найдено.

```
insert(Info) ->
  Id = float_to_list(rand:uniform(),[{decimals,4}]),
  Status = true,
  {Mega, Sec, Micro} = os:timestamp(),
  Time = (Mega*1000000 + Sec)*1000 + round(Micro/1000),

    emysql:prepare(id, <<"INSERT INTO vobla SET id = ?">>),
    emysql:prepare(status, <<"UPDATE vobla SET status = ? WHERE id = ?">>),
    emysql:prepare(time, <<"UPDATE vobla SET time = ? WHERE id = ?">>),
    emysql:prepare(info, <<"UPDATE vobla SET info = ? WHERE id = ?">>),

    emysql:execute(erlang, id, [Id]),
    emysql:execute(erlang, status, [Status, Id]),
    emysql:execute(erlang, time, [Time, Id]),
    Result = emysql:execute(erlang, info, [Info, Id]),
      io:format("stored ~n~p~n", [Result]).
```